# How to send very big amount of email notifications with sails app?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, sails.js

all. In my nodejs-sails app i'm need to send very big amount of email notifications (>1kk in month) fast. What most efficient and cheap way of doing this? I'm not know very good how all this mailing stuff work, so please show me the way for further googling.

Do i'm need to rent smtp server, use software like Haraka or anything else? Or maybe i need to use Amazon SES?

Thank for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the most efficient way is going to be a third party email service.

As Jeff Atwood (co-founder of SO) puts it "Email sucks;" 
http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/

As an example, I use Mandrill's SMTP service over Nodemailer:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Mandrill',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MANDRILL_USER,
      pass: process.env.MANDRILL_API_KEY
    }
});
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@address',
    to: 'receiver@address',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello world!'
});
```

Nodemailer supports all sorts of transports and services out of the box. Docs here: https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer

Comment: Thank you, Mandrill don't look cheap solution

Comment: If Mandrill isn't cheap enough, then [nodemailer has a SES transport](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-ses-transport)